# Modifying set_Basis values for a transform in Revit

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am using a transform in Revit to show elevation views of individual beams (for the purpose of detailing).  This works fine as long as the beam is flat (identical start and end offsets), but if I have a beam that is sloping, I am forced to "flatten" the endpoints.

I tried to define a unit vector along the actual start/end points, and a perpendicular to that vector on an XY plane running through the defined ".Origin" of the transform.  I then used simple equations to define a normal to those two vectors...
    double newx = first.Y * second.Z - first.Z * second.Y;
    double newy = first.Z * second.X - first.X * second.Z;
    double newz = first.X * second.Y - first.Y * second.X;
    double vectlong = Math.Sqrt(newx * newx + newy * newy + newz * newz);
    XYZ normal = new Autodesk.Revit.DB.XYZ(newx / vectlong, newy / vectlong, newz / vectlong);

I then used those three vectors as my ".set_Basis" 0, 1 & 2.

This code works as long as I've forced the beam's start and end points to be flat (which shows that the generated "normal" is valid), but when I remove the code to flatten and use the actual Z values of the endpoints of a sloping beam, the program fails when I try to use these values.

The SDK sample to generate a section through the middle of a beam (CreateViewSection) seems to have found the same problem, but the programmer gave up and simply forces the program to accept only beams that are already on the same XY plane, which is not really the "rule" for beams.

I exported the calculated values of my three vectors and verified that they were all unit length and orthonormal, which should be all that is required for the transform.  Can anyone explain why these basis values fail?

Comment: Update:  I have tried rotating a view of a column, by hand, to lie flat (which is the most typical view of a column for fabricators), and Revit "Helps" me so that when I rotate the view 90 degrees, the view automatically reverts back to vertical (for a hidden reason nobody could possibly justify).  I would still like to make a view of a beam on a 4:12 roof slope and have it display flat.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code to set assembly transform. It will align assembly origin and axis properly so that assembly views are always aligned to XYZ axis!

```
                    var assyTransform = Transform.Identity;
                    var beamInst = mainElement as FamilyInstance;
                    if( beamInst != null )
                    {
                        assyTransform = beamInst.GetTransform();
                        assyTransform.Origin = ( assyInstance.Location as LocationPoint ).Point;
                    }

                    if ( !assyInstance.GetTransform()
                        .AlmostEqual( assyTransform ) )
                    {
                        assyInstance.SetTransform( assyTransform );
                        return true;
                    }
```